Second cohomology of nonabelian finite simple group vanishes.
$\DeclareMathOperator{Hom}{Hom}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{Ext}{Ext}$
Given a nonabelian finite simple group $G$, how to prove that: $H_1(G)=H^1(G)=H^2(G)=0$?
I know that $H_1(G)=G/[G,G]$ is the abelianization of $G$, which vanishes as $G$ is nonabelian and simple.
By Universal coeffient theorem, $H^1(G)=\Hom(H_1(G),\mathbb{Z})\oplus\Ext^1(H_0(G),\mathbb{Z})$. $H_0(G)=\mathbb{Z}$, the Ext term is $\Ext^1(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})=0$ as $\mathbb{Z}$ projective. Therefore $H^1(G)=0$.
It remains to treat $H^2(G)$ or $H_2(G)$. I don't know a general formula for $H_2(G)$ or $H^2(G)$ so the proof above doesn't work. The calculation via canonical resolution is tedious and I gain few information.

Let $G$ be a finite group. We have
$$H^2(G)\cong \operatorname{Hom}(H_2(G),\mathbb{Z})\oplus \operatorname{Ext}(H_1(G),\mathbb{Z}).$$
Now $H_2(G)$ is finite (it is finitely generated and killed by $|G|$) so $\operatorname{Hom}(H_2(G),\mathbb{Z})=0$. If $G=[G,G]$ then $H_1(G)=0$ so $\operatorname{Ext}(H_1(G),\mathbb{Z})=0$. Thus $H^2(G)=0$.
More generally, if $G$ is finite but without assuming $G=[G,G]$, $H^2(G)$ is the Pontryagin dual of $H_1(G)\cong G/[G,G]$.

$H_2(G) = M(G)$ is the Schur Multiplier of the group $G$. This is known for all finite simple groups $G$, and you can find them listed in the ATLAS of Finite Groups, for example.
They are certainly no all $0$. For example, the smallest finite  simple group $A_5$ has Schur Multiplier of order $2$.

There's also a nice paper of Bob Griess that gives a summary of the Schur multipliers of the finite simple groups.
